# PHP - How pass user input date from one form (page) to another filling in the same info for the user to verify

Tags: php

I'm trying to create an order form that will pass data from it to the same form but on a different page so the user can verify their information first then they will submit the data again for emailing and be redirected to a thank you page.

The problem is I haven't been able to get the info to pass into the form (same form different page). I also have to set up a conditional when the email(s) is sent because it needs to be sent to different people depending on which parts of the form are filled out.

Any help is greatly appreciated! I have a pretty good grasp of PHP, but it's been a long time since I've used it and this has been frustrating after spending a few days online searching for an answer. I'm sure this is something easy and I'll say, "Of course".

Thank you!

https://secure.kellypromotions.com/hmcpromo/order_form.php

https://secure.kellypromotions.com/hmcpromo/verify_order_roller.php

```
<form id="promo_order_form" name="promo_order_form" method="post" action="verify_order_form.php">

    <div id="order_form">
        <span id="sprytextfield7">
            <label for="Order_Date">Order Date:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Order_Date" id="Order_Date" />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span id="sprytextfield17">
            <label for="Date_Needed">Date Needed:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Date_Needed" id="Date_Needed" />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span id="sprytextfield16">
            <label for="AU">AU #:</label>
            <input type="text" name="AU" id="AU" />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
        <br />
        (Required for ALL orders, including credit card orders)
        <br />
        <br />
        <span id="sprytextfield15">
            <label for="Approved">Approved by:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Approved" id="Approved" />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
        <br />
        (Managers approval required)
        <br />
        <br />
        <span id="sprytextfield5">
            <label for="mgrEmail">Manager Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="mgrEmail" id="mgrEmail" />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span id="sprytextfield14">
            <label for="Contact">Contact:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Contact" id="Contact" />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span id="sprytextfield13">
            <label for="Email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span id="sprytextfield12">
            <label for="Phone1">Phone #:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Phone1" id="Phone1" />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span id="sprytextfield8">
            <label for="Fax">Fax #:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Fax" id="Fax" />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span id="sprytextfield9">
            <label for="MAC">MAC #:</label>
            <input type="text" name="MAC" id="MAC" />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span id="sprytextfield10">
            <label for="Ship">Ship to:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Ship" id="Ship" />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span id="sprytextfield11">
            <label for="Attention">Attention:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Attention" id="Attention" />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>

    <div id="personal_form">
        <div id="personal_header">PERSONAL ORDERS ONLY:</div>

        <span id="spryradio1">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="Visa" value="radio" id="Visa" />
                Visa</label>
            <br />
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="Mastercard" value="radio" id="Mastercard" />
                Mastercard</label>
            <br />
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="Amex" value="radio" id="Amex" />
                Amex</label>
        </span>

        <span id="sprytextfield21">
            <label for="CardNum">Card Number:</label>
            <input type="text" name="CardNum" id="CardNum" />
        </span>
        <br />
        <br />

        <span id="sprytextfield18">
            <label for="exp">EXP:</label>
            <input name="exp" type="text" id="exp" value="MM/DD" size="10" maxlength="5" />
        </span>

        <span id="sprytextfield20">
            <label for="cvs">CVS #:</label>
            <input name="cvs" type="text" id="cvs" size="5" maxlength="3" />
        </span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span id="sprytextfield19">
            <label for="auth">Name on Card:</label>
            <input name="auth" type="text" id="auth" size="40" />
        </span>
    </div>

    <div id="delivery">
        <p>Please allow 3 weeks for delivery.
            <br />
            <br />
            Orders will ship via UPS Ground. Individual product styles will ship separately.
        </p>
    </div>

    <br />
    <ul>
        <li class="clear">PERSONALIZATION INFORMATION</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="pers_form">
        <span id="sprytextfield3">
            <label for="First">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="First" id="First" />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>

        <span id="sprytextfield2">
            <label for="Last">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Last" id="Last" />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span><br /><br />

        <span id="sprytextfield4">
            <label for="Phone2">Phone #:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Phone2" id="Phone2" />
        </span>

        <span id="sprytextfield1">
            <label for="Email2">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Email2" id="Email2" />
        </span>
    </div>

    <div id="totals_header">
        TOTAL COST
    </div>

    <br />
    <ul>
        <li>ITEM</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="item_form">
        <h3>Executive Metal Grip Roller</h3>
        <input name="ItemNum" type="hidden" id="ItemNum" value="EMGR" />
        <br />
        <input name="ItemPrice" type="text" id="ItemPrice" value="$1.10 Each" size="12" readonly="readonly" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <span id="sprytextfield6">
            <label for="Qty">Qty (Minimum 300):</label>
            <input name="Qty" type="text" id="Qty" size="10" />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span          class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span><span class="textfieldMinValueMsg">The entered value is less than the minimum required.</span>  </span><br />
        <br />
        <label for="Total">Total:</label>
        <input name="Total" type="text" id="Total" size="25" readonly="readonly" />
        <br />
        <hr />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
        <br />
    </div>

    <div id="totals_form">
        <label for="Subtotal">Subtotal</label>
        <input name="Subtotal" type="text" id="Subtotal" size="15" readonly="readonly" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label for="Sales_Tax">Sales Tax (MN only)</label>
        <input name="Sales_Tax" type="text" id="Sales_Tax" size="15" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label for="P_H">Packaging and Handling</label>
        <input name="P_H" type="text" id="P_H" value="$3.75" size="15" readonly="readonly" />
        <br />
        <br />  
        <label for="Freight">Freight</label>
        <input name="Freight" type="text" id="Freight" size="15" readonly="readonly" />
        <br />
        <hr />
        <label for="Totals">Total</label>
        <input name="Totals" type="text" id="Totals" size="15" readonly="readonly" />
    </div>

    <div class="clear"><!--CLEAR--></div>

</form>


<?php

//Order Form Var
$Order_Date = strip_tags($_POST['Order_Date']);
$Date_Needed = strip_tags($_POST['Date_Needed']);
$AU = strip_tags($_POST['AU']);
$Approved = strip_tags($_POST['Approved']);
$mgrEmail = strip_tags($_POST['mgrEmail']);
$Contact = strip_tags($_POST['Contact']);
$Email = strip_tags($_POST['Email']);
$Phone1 = strip_tags($_POST['Phone1']);
$Fax = strip_tags($_POST['Fax']);
$MAC = strip_tags($_POST['MAC']);
$Ship = strip_tags($_POST['Ship']);
$Attention = strip_tags($_POST['Attention']);

//Personal Order Form Var
$Visa = strip_tags($_POST['Visa']);
$Mastercard = strip_tags($_POST['Mastercard']);
$Amex = strip_tags($_POST['Amex']);
$exp = strip_tags($_POST['exp']);
$cvs = strip_tags($_POST['cvs']);
$auth = strip_tags($_POST['auth']);

//Personalization Form Var
$First = strip_tags($_POST['First']);
$Last = strip_tags($_POST['Last']);
$Phone2 = strip_tags($_POST['Phone2']);
$Email2 = strip_tags($_POST['Email2']);

//Item Form Var and Math
$ItemNum = strip_tags($_POST['ItemNum']);
$ItemPrice = strip_tags($_POST['ItemPrice']);
$ItemNum = strip_tags($_POST['ItemNum']);
$Qty = strip_tags($_POST['Qty']);
$Total = strip_tags($_POST['Total']);

//Totals Form Math
$Subtotal = strip_tags($_POST['Subtotal']);
$Sales_Tax = strip_tags($_POST['Sales_Tax']);
$P_H = strip_tags($_POST['P_H']);
$Freight = strip_tags($_POST['Freight']);
$Totals = strip_tags($_POST['Totals']);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start();
```

and then

```
$_SESSION['key1'] = $val1;
$_SESSION['key2'] = $val2;
```

Do that for all the data. And then access the stuff using $_SESSION['key']

Answer (score 1):

Your form is already posting to the second form so you don't need session variables. You can retrieve the values using `$_POST['input_name']` on the verify page, if you need to verify what fields are being posted to the page you can use `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: Thanks! That helped. Would you happen to know how to pass a radio button value on as well? It's the only thing left that's not passing. I've tried a few different ways but they don't seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: they work the same way, each group will have the same name and a value must be declared in order for something to be posted